# Adding a TrackBar in ToolStrip

Tags: c#, toolstrip, trackbar, toolstripcontrolhost

I am trying to add a TrackBar in my ToolStrip. I have found this code somewhere on the net but I am not sure how to use it as it should be compiled maybe?

**Code**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds trackbar to toolstrip stuff
    /// </summary>
    [
    ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability
        (ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ToolStrip | ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.StatusStrip)
    ]

    public class ToolStripTraceBarItem : ToolStripControlHost
    {
        public ToolStripTraceBarItem(): base(new TrackBar())
        {
        }
    }
```

Any tips will be appriciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply copy this code in your form source file. (You also need to import some extra stuff, `using System.Windows.Forms.Design;`).

Then you'll be able to see `TraceBarItem` in the designer when you try to add an element to your toolstrip.

To customize your TraceBar, add this to the constructor of the class you posted:

`TrackBar tb = (TrackBar)this.Control;`

You can set all the trackbar's properties using that `tb` object.